# JSP: How to update a bean with JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, javabeans

I'm trying to create a Christmas shopping list `jsp` page.

I need to check if a `PresentBean` item already exists and if so update the existing `PresentBean` item with the parameters from the form. This way there should be no duplicate `PresentBean`.

So basically the question is how do I update my bean?

1.`PresentBean` - A bean that stores item, price, and person.

```
 /*
 *
 * PresentBean.java
 * 
 */
package win.net;



/**
 *
 * @author aubrey - 
 */
public class PresentBean {

    private String item;
    private String person;
    private String price;

    //constructor
    public PresentBean(){
    item = new String();
    person = new String();
    price = new String();

    }

    /**
     * @return the item
     */
    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * @param item the item to set
     */
    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    /**
     * @return the person
     */
    public String getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    /**
     * @param person the person to set
     */
    public void setPerson(String person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    /**
     * @return the price
     */
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * @param price the price to set
     */
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

2.`ListBean` - A bean that stores multiple `PresentBean`:

```
package win.net;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author aubrey
 */
public class ListBean {

private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

public void setChild(Object object){
    list.add(object);
}
public List<Object> getList(){
    return list;
}

}
```

3.`jsp` Page - Collects form parameters and puts them in a `PresentBean`. Then it puts the `PresentBean` in a list. Finally we print the list of `PresentBeans`:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : 04-Jul-2018, 23:32:58
    Author     : aubrey
--%>

<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Christmas</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input">

        <h1>Christmas</h1>

        <jsp:useBean id="chris" class="win.net.PresentBean" />

                 <%-- Create the Bean --%>   
                 <%--jsp:useBean id='listBean' class='win.net.SetBean' scope='session'/--%>                 
                 <jsp:useBean id='listBean' class='win.net.ListBean' scope='session' />

                 <%-- Search for duplicates --%>
                 <c:forEach var="v" begin="0" items="${listBean.list}">
                     <c:if test="${v.item ne param.item}">
                         <% System.out.println("Not equal"); %>
                                <jsp:setProperty name="chris" property="item"/>
                                <jsp:setProperty name="chris" property="price"/>
                                <jsp:setProperty name="chris" property="person"/>


                     </c:if>

                     <c:if test="${v.item eq param.item}">
                         <% System.out.println("Equal"); %>

                     </c:if>
                 </c:forEach>


        <c:set target='${listBean}' property='child' value='${chris}'/>




        <form action="index.jsp" method="get">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="item" value="${param.item}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Price:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="price" value="${param.price}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Person:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="person" value="${param.person}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                <br/>
        </form>
        </div>




                <div class="panel">



                 <%-- Print out the box links --%>
                 <c:forEach var="v" begin="0" items="${listBean.list}">
                     <c:if test="${not empty v.item}">

                <a href="index.jsp?item=${v.item}&person=${v.person}&price=${v.price}">         
                <div class="box">        
                 Item: <c:out value="${v.item}" /><br/>
                 Person: <c:out value="${v.person}" /><br/>
                 Price: &euro; <c:out value="${v.price}" /><br/>
                 <br/>
                </div>
                </a>
                     </c:if>
                 </c:forEach >


                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

4. Here's the code I'm trying to get working. Basically I do a test to see if the duplicate item exists. If so it should update the bean. If not it should just add the item to the list.

First I create both beans. The PresentBean is called "chris" and the ListBean is called "listBean". But they are not accessible from within the loop.

```
<jsp:useBean id="chris" class="win.net.PresentBean" />   


                 <jsp:useBean id='listBean' class='win.net.ListBean' scope='session' />

                 <%-- Search for duplicates --%>
                 <c:forEach var="v" begin="0" items="${listBean.list}">
                     <c:if test="${v.item ne param.item}">
                         <% System.out.println("Not equal"); %>
                                <jsp:setProperty name="chris" property="item"/>
                                <jsp:setProperty name="chris" property="price"/>
                                <jsp:setProperty name="chris" property="person"/>


                     </c:if>

                     <c:if test="${v.item eq param.item}">
                         <% System.out.println("Equal"); %>

                     </c:if>
                 </c:forEach>


        <c:set target='${listBean}' property='child' value='${chris}'/>
```

For example if I move the line:

```
<c:set target='${listBean}' property='child' value='${chris}'/>
```

to inside the loop it fails. I think it the problem is that I'm trying to add to a list that I'm currently iterating over. Or it could be that the variable is out of scope! So how do I call this line inside the not equal part of the loop?

Comment: So basically I need a function that  checks if a present item exits. If so update the existing present details. If not just add the present to the list.

Comment: you need to post the code that is actually relevant to this. The bean and the jsp doesn't help. Wherever you get your data from, you need to do the sorting there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. It seems I was iterating over an empty list.